# Conditional deletion from array of field A with condition on field B

Tags: json, jq

Let's say I have a json with an array inside. Say that the elements of this array are objects with keys A and B. I would like to remove the B objects on the elements where A objects meet a certain condition. 
For example, I would like to remove the B objects where A is greater than 5, transforming

```
{
  "title": "myTitle",
  "myArray": [
     {
        "A": 1,
        "B": "foo"
     },
     {
        "A": 4,
        "B": "bar"
     },
     {
        "A": 7,
        "B": "barfoo"
     },
     {
        "A": 9,
        "B": "foobar"
     }
  ]
}
```

into

```
{
  "title": "myTitle",
  "myArray": [
     {
        "A": 1,
        "B": "foo"
     },
     {
        "A": 4,
        "B": "bar"
     },
     {
        "A": 7
     },
     {
        "A": 9
     }
  ]
}
```

The task seems easy enough and if I had't have to keep the A's it would be a simple del(select..) thing. There surely must be an elegant way to do this as well?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use a *del(select..) thing*.

```
.myArray[] |= del(select(.A > 5) .B)
```

<sup>[demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/KQXrjYzExd)</sup>

Comment: Yes! It works! Thank you so much!

I still needed quite some time to figure out why it works. It is because when in one case 'select' returns the current element, redefining .myArray[i] = del(myArray[i].B) and in the other case .myArray[j] = del(empty.B), not deleting anything, right?
It's a genius trick, I would never have figured it out by myself, although I knew how the single elements worked.

Can you suggest me any good sources of information on similar usages? The docs are not enough for me to "connects the dots" ;)

Comment: @Jernej You're welcome. Yes, that's almost what's happening there; `select` yields `.` when `.A` is greater than 5, and `empty` otherwise, resulting in either `del(. .B)` or `del(empty .B)`. And sorry, I don't know of any other reliable source than the manual and wiki, there's also [this](https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq) but I personally regard it a bit newbie-unfriendly